# VB macro - run-time error '13' on for each loop

Tags: vba, excel

i know there might have been questions like this. But i'm really unfamiliar with VB, so i need help please. Here is the part of the code:

```
    Sub Convert_to_Digi()

    Dim SrcWkb As Workbook
    Dim csvWkb As Workbook
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim wkbname As Variant
    Dim xlsFiles As Variant
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim NewName As Variant
    Dim csvName As String

    StartRow = 2

    ' Get the workbooks to open
    xlsFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xls), *.xls", MultiSelect:=True)
    If VarType(xlsFiles) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub

    ' Loop through each workbook and copy the data to this CSV
     For Each wkbname In xlsFiles
        Set SrcWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wkbname, ReadOnly:=False)
        Set srcSheet = SrcWkb.Worksheets("export_label_conf")

        ' Get used range on sheet
        Set MyRange = srcSheet.UsedRange
        ' Adjust to exclude top row
        Set MyRange = MyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(MyRange.Rows.Count - 1)

        NewName = srcSheet.Cells(2, 10) & ".csv"

        If MyRange.Row + MyRange.Rows.Count - 1 >= StartRow Then
            Set csvWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\DIGITAL\template.csv", ReadOnly:=False)

            ' copy column A
            MyRange.Columns(1).Copy
            ' paste into CSV template file, column I
            csvWkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            ' and save template as new CSV with barcode as name
            csvName = "C:\DIGITAL\" & NewName
            csvWkb.SaveAs Filename:=csvName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        End If

        SrcWkb.Close
    Next wkbname

End Sub
```

i get this error on ***For Each wkbname In xlsFiles*** line. wkbname is empty, while xlsFiles contains name of a file to open (but only 1, while it should have few...)

and only a short while ago it was working fine! i undone all i could remember i done, but didn't solve the problem....

Comment: Start using a version control system (Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, SVN, ...), and you will never again get problems of the form "and only a short while ago it was working fine".

Comment: run-time error 13 is a type mismatch I think

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? It looks like it got cut off before the end of the `For Each` loop.

Comment: i only write macros once i year may be.. i don't have opportunity to install any programs on my PC at work... thanks for understanding

Comment: i ran this (changing paths as appropriate) and it ran fine in Excel 2007 [status-norepro]

Comment: i ran it fine as well, but i hadn't change a thing since posting here! very interesting....

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to do as follows:

- Try compile your code. Sounds dummy, but might point a problem somewhere else that could be impacting in this piece of code.
- Change the variable names. If there's an Excel problem happening for any reason (variant confusion) it could solve the problem.
- Check the project's References. If there's a missing reference, VBA doesn't work as usual.

Just tried the below code here and worked fine... and it's pretty much the same as yours (besides variable names).

```
Public Sub OpenExcelFiles()

    Dim vFiles As Variant
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim oXLFile As Excel.Workbooks

    vFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xls), *.xls", MultiSelect:=True)

    If VarType(xlsFiles) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub

    For Each vFile In vFiles

        Set oXLFile = Workbooks.Open(vFile)

    Next vFile

End Sub
```